# What is the necessary header file for prvGetInterruptControllerInstance() function in FreeRTOS?

Tags: c, fpga, freertos

I am trying to link the interrupt of the fpga to FreeRTOS in zedboard. When I write the code:

```
InterruptController = (XScuGic *)prvGetInterruptControllerInstance();
```

I get an error from Xilinx SDK said:

```
undefined reference to `prvGetInterruptControllerInstance'
```

May I know what is the necessary include header file to use that function? I tried to search online and I have the same header file included:

```
/* FreeRTOS includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "FreeRTOSConfig.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "semphr.h"

/* Xilinx includes. */
#include "xil_printf.h"
#include "xparameters.h"
#include <xil_io.h>
#include "xscugic.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

Thank you!

Comment: look at compilation output and assert you link to the definition of prvGetInterruptControllerInstance

Comment: ../src/FreeRTOS_DMA.c: In function 'InitInterrupt':
../src/FreeRTOS_DMA.c:156:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'prvGetInterruptControllerInstance' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  InterruptController = (XScuGic *)prvGetInterruptControllerInstance();
  ^
'Finished building: ../src/FreeRTOS_DMA.c'
' '

Comment: 'Building target: FreeRTOS_DMA.elf'
'Invoking: ARM v7 gcc linker'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,-build-id=none -specs=Xilinx.spec -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -L../../FreeRTOS_DMA_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib -o "FreeRTOS_DMA.elf"  ./src/FreeRTOS_DMA.o   -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lfreertos,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group

Comment: ./src/FreeRTOS_DMA.o: In function `InitInterrupt':
C:\H_Bridge_Vivado\IQ_Demodulation\I_Q_Demodulation\I_Q_Demodulation.sdk\FreeRTOS_DMA\Debug/../src/FreeRTOS_DMA.c:156: undefined reference to `prvGetInterruptControllerInstance'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [FreeRTOS_DMA.elf] Error 1
23:01:40 Build Finished (took 959ms)

Comment: This is what I get, and it doesn't point me to the definition...

Answer (score 0):

1- Your IDE may help you find the header file : right click on the function name, then click on go to the definition, once you get the header file eg `file.h` you should include it.

2-Your `# include`assume that the header files `freeRTOS.h`... are in the same folder but possibly they are in other folders,
I said that because `freeRTOSConfig.h`is a configuration file that should not be in the same folder as the kernel include files`task.h`,...,(at least in the demo project) so make sure that you use the good local /global path to your headers

3- The order of include is not good i guess, the best approach is to go from global to local, `stdio.h` for example should be at the top of the includes

Comment: I did try clicking goto defination but it return me "Cound not find symbol 'prvGetInterruptControllerInstance' in index. The IDE redirect me to the correct file for freeRTOS.h and freeRTOSConfig.h when I click go to definition (Ctril+Click in Xilinx SDK). I am not sure why...do you encounter such problem before?I am trying to pass the fpga interrupt to freertos

Comment: No, i didn't work with, but googling this function i find that it is defined in `port.c`,  these funcions are private functions used by the kernel i don't know why yo wanna call such functions, there should be equivalent to this function in the kernel API, 2- if you want use a function it should be at first declared in a .h  and then include this .h or possibly use "extern" to tell the compiler that this function is defined else where

Comment: I tried to search in port.c before and I didn't find the definition in that file....I think I should rollback to older version...

Comment: Maybe, i find it [here https://github.com/ykoh/freertos_zynq/blob/master/bsp/freertos_zynq/src/Source/portable/GCC/Zynq/port.c

Comment: Haha...we found at the exact same file. Unfortunately (and I don't know why), in my port.c, it is sort of different. I am not sure if thats my setup problem or it is because is a newer version. Thank you very much.